# jQuery - remove previously added instances of a class

Tags: jquery

i'm adding a class to an `<a>` tag on "click". now i need to remove this class when another `<a>` is clicked. how can i do this?

thanks

EDIT: the html is an unordered list

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
 <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
 <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing the html, this is rough.

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('a').removeClass('red')
   $(this).addClass('red');
   return false;
})
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SgaW6/)

based on your EDIT, the best approach I could suggest is

```
$('li a').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('red')
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .children('a')
        .removeClass('red');

    return false;
})​;
```

## [humble demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SgaW6/1/)

if your classes are just meant for CSS purpose, I would suggest to add/remove class on `li`, to minimize codes on javascript part.

```
$('li a').click(function() {

    $(this).parent()
        .addClass('red')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('red');

    return false;
})​;
```

then have your CSS

**Before**

```
a.red {
   color: red;
}
```

**after**

```
li.red a {
    color: red;
}
```

## [cool demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SgaW6/3/)

Answer (score 3):

here's one

```
var lastSelected;

$('ul').delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {

    if(lastSelected) {
        lastSelected.removeClass('selected');
    }

    lastSelected = $(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

Comment: +1 for using delegate and encouraging it's use here, where it is well suited.

Comment: yeah, `delegate`'s my favorite *function* in jQuery's event-related stuff (favorite *functionality* would be event namespaces :D)